# Replace nth line in a text file

Tags: r, file-manipulation

How do I go about in replacing the nth line of a text file in R?

Comment: Have you looked at help(readLines)?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To the person who silently downvoted: This is the [summer of love](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/kicking-off-the-summer-of-love/), so I suggest you do one of a few things 1) Explain why the downvote, 2) Explain to the OP how to improve the question 3) Edit the question so it is a good question.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I had looked at readLines but I did not know about writeLines.

Comment: @Simanner: I recommend you always read the "See Also" section of the help pages.  Had you read the "See Also" section of `?readLines`, you would have seen `writeLines`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To replace the third line of this:

```
$ cat junk.txt
sic transit
gloria mundi
temeo danoas
et dona ferentes
```

Do this:

```
> latin = readLines("junk.txt",-1)
> latin[3]="per ardua ad astra"
> writeLines(latin,"junkout.txt")
```

and get:

```
$ cat junkout.txt 
sic transit
gloria mundi
per ardua ad astra
et dona ferentes
```

You can `writeLines(latin,"junk.txt")` and overwrite the input file if you want.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there is an option to change a specific line in the streaming file (seek in file), although you have the option to read the file , change a column and write the the frame to a file, read, write functions supply you what you need.

You may also use `read.table()` to read the file into a table format, change specific row and then `write.table()`

you have options like `read.csv()` and `write.csv()` and many other options like `readLines()`.

**EDIT**

Here is a wiki link for [file handling in R](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/R_Programming/Text_Processing)

Comment: Please be careful when posting answers. R is case-sensitive, so `readlines` is not the same as `readLines`, and there is actually a function `readline`.